# SQL Server uses - Index Scan instead of Index Seek

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

Azure SQL Server has a simple table with three columns, all of which are part of the Clustered Index. The select query that filters using two of those columns and returns the third column uses Index Scan instead of Index Seek. A total of 500k records are being scanned and the CPU usage is high and the execution is slow

[image]

Clustered Index

[image]

Are there any reasons to not use Index Seek? Should I create the non-clustered index as suggested?

Comment: It's not seeking due to order of columns in the index : you filter by non-leading columns.... that's why there is an index suggested.

Comment: Should I move the UPC column to be bottom of the Index? Or would you suggest to create the non-clustered index? What is the best solution that would be impact both the Select & Insert operations

Comment: I don't know your entire query workload, so I can't say what will be the best design.

Comment: This table get loaded once in a day and being read multiple times in a day. It has about 500k records.

Comment: Yes swapping the columns round would do the job. If it wasn't a primary key you could instead make `UPC` an `INCLUDE` column. Is the primary key correct anyway, it does look somewhat unusual? Do not blindly follow index suggestions, they are just that: suggestions, useful for analysis only

Comment: Without further information, it's hard to make a firm recommendation, but I would recommend that you NOT rearrange the columns in the primary key.  That change could improve this query at the expense of other queries that use UPC as the principal selection or join criteria. I recommend creating a new non-clustered index containing one or both of the tag_text_category_cd or line_sequence_nbr columns. SQL Server does tend to over-recommend how many columns to include in indexes. My rule of thumb is to include columns that significantly narrow the selection, and omit columns that are "just data".